# How to put a text message with an SMS Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Android application I use the following code to send SMS:

```
String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this); // Need to change the build to API 19

             Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
             sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
             sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "sujet");
             sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myMessage);
             sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"+phoneNumber));
             if (defaultSmsPackageName != null)// Can be null in case that there is no default, then the user would be able to choose
             // any app that support this intent.
             {
                sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
             }
             startActivity(sendIntent);
```

However when the Message application (Hangout for instance) is launched, I have the right recipient but the message ("myMessage") is not there. How can I put it in the Intent to make it appear?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send SMS as below

```
String phoneNumber = "0123456789";
String message = "Hello World!";

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Read more about [SMS Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html) in the docs.

Comment: The problem is this does not work with the lastest Android versions.